# GData Picasa Photo Album iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata-api, picasa

I was hoping someone could help me with this problem. I am trying to access a Picasa Web Album from my iphone application. I have used GData previously with Google Calendar and getting events and the data related to them before, so I set up my methods in a similar fashion. I however am getting an error that is telling me the following

```
serviceBase:<GDataServiceGooglePhotos: 0x4d4e6d0> objectFetcher:<GDataHTTPFetcher: 0xbaa35c0> failedWithStatus:400 data:Too many results requested
```

I am think that I have narrowed down the problem that I am having has something to do with the *ticket* that I am using, in the following line

```
ticket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kGDataGooglePhotosAllFeed]
                          delegate:self
                 didFinishSelector:@selector(photosListTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
```

I however am unable to get past this problem. Does anyone have a suggestion to get past this problem. Am I doing something wrong?

My full code for the retrieval of the pictures is shown below. Anywhere that says picAlbum, that is a predefined NSArray to hold the information.

```
- (GDataServiceGooglePhotos *)photoService {

    static GDataServiceGooglePhotos* service = nil;
    if (!service) {
        service = [[GDataServiceGooglePhotos alloc] init];
        [service setShouldCacheDatedData:YES];
        [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
    }

    [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:@"username"
                                   password:@"password"];
    return service;
}


-(void)loadGooglePhotos {
    [self fetchAllPhotos];
}

-(void)fetchAllPhotos {
    NSLog(@"In fetchAllPhotos");
    GDataServiceGooglePhotos *service = [self photoService];
    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;

    ticket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kGDataGooglePhotosKindAlbum]
                              delegate:self
                     didFinishSelector:@selector(photosListTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
}

- (void)photosListTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedPhotoAlbum *)feed error:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"In photosListTicket");
    NSArray *photos = [feed entries];
    if ([photos count] != 0){
        self.picAlbum = [photos objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"fetching photos");
        [self fetchPhotos];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"User has no photos...");
    }
}

- (void)fetchPhotos {

    NSLog(@"In fetchPhotos");
    if (self.picAlbum) {
        NSURL *feedURL = [[self.picAlbum alternateLink] URL];
        if (feedURL) {
            NSLog(feedURL);
            GDataQueryGooglePhotos *query = [GDataQueryGooglePhotos photoQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];
            [query setMaxResults:1000];
            GDataServiceGooglePhotos *service = [self photoService];
            GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
            ticket = [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(photosEventsTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
        }
    }
}

- (void)photosEventsTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedPhotoAlbum *)feed error:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"In photosEventsTicket");
    NSArray *photos = [feed entries];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[photos count]]);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any information or help that you can provide.

Comment: I still have yet be able to get the photo content and all of that from the albums, but I did get past the whole problem with too many requests. It turns out that the url I was using was accessing all feeds that are present on Picasa, worldwide. So that would explain the too many results thing. What I was able to do was use a different method to get a url, which I found after some searching

NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGooglePhotos photoFeedURLForUserID:@"username" albumID:nil albumName:@"album name" photoID:nil kind:nil access:nil];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server says "Too many results requested" that's a clue that the max results query parameter is too big.

The fetches in the code snippet do not appear functional.  Neither kGDataGooglePhotosKindAlbum nor an album's alternateLink would be URLs for feeds.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to what I could use instead because I have tried changing everything and have not been very lucky